# Creating in MS-SQL a primary key results in a dynamic index name format eg PK__dummy__3213E83F2E1BDC42

Tags: sql-server

Hope for help because of the following problem. Assume we have a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dummy](
    [id] [char](36) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

If I create a primary key like this (version 1)

```
ALTER TABLE dummy ADD CONSTRAINT PK_dummy PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

I get a unique name. In this case PK_dummy.
But if I create a primary key like this (version 2)

```
ALTER TABLE dummy ADD PRIMARY KEY Clustered (ID);
```

The name changes with every recreation of this primary key.
The format is always PK__dummy__"a dynamic number"

What is the meaning of this number?
And how can I identify primary keys created with version 2 in a hugh database?

Thanks for hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the meaning of this number?

[This depends on product version](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/236796/3690) - it is either based on a unique id or generated randomly.

> how can I identify primary keys created with version 2 in a huge database?

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.key_constraints
WHERE is_system_named = 1
```

Comment: perfetc. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't define the name of a constraint, index, key, etc, SQL Server will give it a name. To ensure uniqueness across the database, it therefore will add "random" characters at the end.

If having a consistent name is important then define the name in your statement, as you did in the first statement.